# Why am I getting segmentation fault (core dumped), and what does it mean?

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, nested-loops, cs50

I am trying to run this piece of code where I get input "message" from a user and I turn that message to binary code. I later print this as lit bulbs for 1 and dark ones for 0 with emojis. However, I keep getting 'segmentation fault (core dumped)' after I enter my input on the terminal. Does anyone know why, and what does it mean in this particular case? Thank you!

```
int main(void)
{
    // prompt for message
    string message = get_string("message: ");
    int len = strlen(message);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int value = message[i];
        int binary_code[BITS_IN_BYTE];

        // convert to binary
        for (int j = 0; j < BITS_IN_BYTE; j++)
        {
            int rem;
            int place = BITS_IN_BYTE - j;
            rem = value % 2;
            binary_code[place] = rem;
            value /= 2;
        }

        // print bulbs
        for (int k = 0; k < BITS_IN_BYTE; k++)
        {
            print_bulb(binary_code[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You access binary_code[] out of bounds, which is an error and is one of the types of error that can produce a seg fault. This is one problem, I am not certain it is the only problem.

Comment: `int place = BITS_IN_BYTE - j;` is `BITS_IN_BYTE` for `j==0`, i.e. one beyond the length of the array.

Comment: Note that `strlen` returns a `size_t` not an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least there is the following problem with your code.

You declared an array with `BITS_IN_BYTE` elements

```
int binary_code[BITS_IN_BYTE];
```

So the valid range of indices is `[0, BITS_IN_BYTE)`.

However when `j` is equal to `0` in this for loop

```
    for (int j = 0; j < BITS_IN_BYTE; j++)
    {
        int rem;
        int place = BITS_IN_BYTE - j;
        rem = value % 2;
        binary_code[place] = rem;
        value /= 2;
    }
```

then the value of the variable `place` is equal to `BITS_IN_BYTE`

```
int place = BITS_IN_BYTE - j;
```

As a result this statement

```
binary_code[place] = rem;
```

writes to memory outside the array that results in undefined behavior.

You should initialize the variable `place` the following way

```
int place = BITS_IN_BYTE - j - 1;
```